# How can I display a Scale in a combo box or drop down button?

Tags: java, swt

I'm working on a translation software in SWT and I want to add a Scale to modify the volume of the audio.
This is what I have in mind:

[image]

Basically, what I want is to be able to show a popup Composite with a Scale widget inside. Is this even possible?
Any help with this is welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: It is certainly possible, the `CCombo` control for example creates a `List` control in a pop-up `Shell`. You could look at the source of that - look at the `createPopup` method for example.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. The `CCombo` code does indeed provide some light on this. I was able to solve this issue based on it.